# Скрипт python не видит больше 9

Tags: python, вконтакте

С другом написали код на питоне, который должен нумеровать комментарии с фото, под постом в вк, но он не нумерует больше 9

```
import vk_api
# Введите ваш API-ключ
api_key = '*'
service_api_key = '*'
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=service_api_key)
vk = vk_session.get_api()

# ID фотографии, на которой нужно нумеровать комментарии
post_id = 1
owner_id = -222793291
# Получаем список комментариев для фотографии
comments = vk.wall.getComments(owner_id=owner_id, post_id=post_id)

# Номер комментария
comment_number = 1
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=api_key)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
# Нумеруем каждый комментарий
for comment in comments['items']:
    photos = [photo for photo in comment.get('attachments', []) if photo.get('photo')]
    if 'post_id' in comment and photos:
        # Если комментарий содержит фото, нумеруем его
        vk.wall.createComment(owner_id=owner_id, post_id=post_id, reply_to_comment=comment['id'], message=f"{comment_number}")
        comment_number += 1

# Выводим сообщение об успешной нумерации комментариев
print("Комментарии успешно пронумерованы!")
```

Answer (score 0):

В функцию `vk.wall.getComments(owner_id=owner_id, post_id=post_id)` нужно передавать `offset` и `comment_id`
По дефолту vk.wall.getComments возвращает 10 комментариев, но можно выводить до 100 комментов, так же  не выводит треды в комментариях.

`offset` позволит перемещаться по комментариям

`comment_id` позволит получать комментарии в тредах

```py
import vk_api


class ParserCommentsVk:
    def __init__(self, api_key: str, service_api_key: str, post_id: int, owner_id: int):
        self.service_api_key_vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=service_api_key).get_api()
        self.api_key_vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=api_key).get_api()
        self.post_id=post_id
        self.owner_id=owner_id
        self.all_comments = []


    def get_all_comments(self, offset: int = 0, count_param: int = 10, comment_id: int = None) -> list:
        while True:
            comments = self.service_api_key_vk_session.wall.getComments(owner_id=self.owner_id, post_id=self.post_id, count=count_param, offset=offset, comment_id=comment_id)
            comments_items = comments.get('items', [])
            self.all_comments.extend(comments_items)
            for comment in comments_items:
                if comment.get('thread') and comment.get('thread').get('count'):
                    self.get_all_comments(comment_id=comment.get('id'), count_param=count_param)
            offset += count_param
            count_all_comments = comments.get('count')
            if len(self.all_comments) >= count_all_comments:
                break
    
    def numbering_comments(self):
    
        self.api_key_vk_session
        count_all_comments = len(self.all_comments)
        for index, comment in enumerate(self.all_comments):
            photos = [photo for photo in comment.get('attachments', []) if photo.get('photo')]
            if 'post_id' in comment and photos:
                # Если комментарий содержит фото, нумеруем его
                self.api_key_vk_session.wall.createComment(owner_id=self.owner_id, post_id=self.post_id, reply_to_comment=comment.get('id'), message=f"{index+1}")
        # Выводим сообщение об успешной нумерации комментариев
        print("Комментарии успешно пронумерованы!")
api_key = '*'
service_api_key = '*'
post_id = 1
owner_id = -222793291
count_param = 100
parser = ParserCommentsVk(api_key=api_key, service_api_key=service_api_key, post_id=post_id, owner_id=owner_id)
parser.get_all_comments(count_param=100)
parser.numbering_comments()
```

По итогу данный код будет брать по 100 комментов верхнего уровня, а так же вложенные комментарии

Comment: Данным кодом я лишь демонстрирую как можно реализовать получение комментариев, отладкой кода не занимался, проверка `if len(self.all_comments) >= count_all_comments:` может не пройти, лучше проверить отдельно и скорректировать проверку